# What is the difference between the link and ln commands?

Tags: hard-link, ln

From the man pages:

```
ln - make links between files
```

and

```
link - call the link function to create a link to a file
```

These seem to do the same thing however `ln` takes a lot of options as well.

Is `link` just a very basic `ln`? Is there any reason to use link over ln?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

link used solely for hard links, calls the link() system function and doesn't perform error checking when attempting to create the link

ln has error checking and can create hard and soft links

Answer (score 8):

The `link` command creates a hard link to a file.

According to the manual page, it is the same as:

```
$ ln --directory --no-target-directory FILENAME LINKNAME
```

See `man link` or `info coreutils 'link invocation'` for more details.